# Destructing an argument gives syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Any idea why I am getting this error ? As I have tried everything I can to solve this but for some reason its not going away , Any help will be a bonus

> ERROR in ./client/components/Material-Form.jsx
>
> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:35)

```
   6 | import validate from "../helpers/validate";
   7 | 
>  8 | const renderRadioGroup = ({ input, ...rest }) => (
     |                                    ^
   9 |   <RadioButtonGroup
  10 |     {...input}
  11 |     {...rest}
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        ["env", {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": "last 2 versions"
            },
            "loose": true,
            "modules": false
        }]
    ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using babel? If so, what do your babel settings look like?

Comment: I have updated it with `.babelrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` and setup inside `"plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]` in your `.babelrc file`.

You can read more about `transform-object-rest-spread` [Here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)

Comment: You are a star !!